# Mule message enricher with query to MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mule

Hey this is my first post here so thanks for any help :)

I am trying to make a flow (using Mule) that reads and transforms a couple of `csv` files to a common format (this part works). After that I want to enrich my messages with 3 objects from a MongoDB. I think I can do that by using one of the attributes in my payload, something like `Payload.MeterUID` to find the document `_id` in the MongoDB and then use 3 of the given `_id` objects to enrich my main message.

This is my `enricher` so far:

```
 <enricher doc:name="Message Enricher">
        <mongo:find-objects config-ref="Mongo_DB1" collection="GSMdata" doc:name="Mongo DB">
        <mongo:query-attributes>
        <mongo:query-attribute key="MeterUID">#[payload.MeterUID]</mongo:query-attribute>
    </mongo:query-attributes>
            <mongo:fields ref="#[payload]"/>
        </mongo:find-objects>
    </enricher>
```

How do I complete this `enricher` so that it works in the way I described, if it is even possible?
At this point any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few problems with your configuration, and one of them is that you are not really stating *how* you want to enrich your message.

Firstly, with `mongo:query-attributes` you need to use `mongo:find-objects-using-query-map`, not `mongo:find-objects`.

Secondly, for `mongo:fields` you need a list of fields you want to return in the query, not a reference to your message payload. If you just need the _id field, then just use

```
<mongo:fields>
    <mongo:field>_id</mongo:field>
</mongo:fields>
```

Thirdly, the enricher needs to know how it should enrich the message. Are you setting a new field in a map payload, or perhaps some property or variable? Assuming you have a map payload, you would specify this as something like `<enricher target="#[payload.my_mongo_id_list]" doc:name="Message Enricher">`.

So, all together:

```
<enricher target="#[payload.my_mongo_id_list]" doc:name="Message Enricher">
    <mongo:find-objects-using-query-map config-ref="Mongo_DB1" collection="GSMdata" doc:name="Mongo DB">
        <mongo:query-attributes>
            <mongo:query-attribute key="MeterUID">#[payload.MeterUID]</mongo:query-attribute>
        </mongo:query-attributes>
        <mongo:fields>
            <mongo:field>_id</mongo:field>
        </mongo:fields>
    </mongo:find-objects-using-query-map>
</enricher>
```

Comment: if my i want these fields from my mongo <mongo:field>IpAddress</mongo:field>
            <mongo:field>LastSetTime</mongo:field>
            <mongo:field>LastReadGsmData</mongo:field> would I then need multiple enricher target's ?

Comment: No, it's all returned as a single Mongo object with multiple fields.